# Cardinality of Prop, Set and Type_i in Coq

Tags: coq, cardinality

Can we assign [cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) in Coq to `Prop`,  `Set` and each `Type_i` ? I only see the definition of [finite cardinals](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Sets.Finite_sets.html) in Coq's library, so maybe we need that of big cardinals to begin with.

According to the proof-irrelevance semantics, for example exposed [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a44b/1b776e1363284c3c0467a2b5c26e67140f42.pdf), `Set` and the `Type_i` form an increasing sequence of [inaccessible cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal). Can this be proven in Coq ?

`Prop` seems more complex because of impredicativity. Proof-irrelevance means we identify all proofs of the same `P : Prop`, and interpret `Prop` itself as the pair `{false, true}`. So the cardinal of `Prop` would be 2. However, for any two proofs `p1 p2 : P`, Coq does not accept `eq_refl p1` as a proof of `p1 = p2`. So Coq does not completely identify `p1` and `p2`. And on the other hand, impredicativity means that for any `A : Type` and `P : Prop`, `A -> P` is of type `Prop`. That makes a lot more inhabitants than in `Set`.

If this is too hard, can Coq prove that `Prop` and `Set` are uncountable ? By [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem), Coq easily proves that there is not surjection `nat -> (nat -> Prop)`. This does not seem very far from proving there is not surjection `nat -> Prop`. But then we need the filter `Prop -> (nat -> Prop)`, that isolates which `Prop`'s have a free `nat` variable. Can we define this filter in Coq, since we cannot pattern-match on `Prop` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to show that `Prop` is uncountable inside Coq.  The [ClassicalFacts](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.ClassicalFacts.html) module in the standard library shows that the axiom of propositional degeneracy, `forall A : Prop, A = True \/ A = False`, is equivalent to the presence of the excluded middle and propositional extensionality.  Since Coq's set theoretic model validates these two axioms, Coq cannot refute degeneracy.

It is certainly possible to show that `Set` and `Type` are infinite, since they contain all types `Fin n` of natural numbers bounded by `n`, and these types are provably different from one another since they have different cardinality.  I suspect that it is possible to show that they are uncountable by adapting the usual diagonalization argument -- that is, assume that some invertible count function `e : nat -> Set`, and try to encode something like the type of all natural numbers that "do not contain themselves". I do not know how you would go about proving that these types are inaccessible cardinals.